# Firebase functions dotenv variable undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, dotenv

I'm running an update of a **Firebase functions project**.

Environment variables was managed with runtime environment configuration (functions.config).
Regarding the recommended way in Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env), i choosed to used file-based configuration of environment variables with dotenv file format.

1 - I ran `firebase functions:config:export` and
**4 dotenv files was created** in the `functions/` folder.
`.env.default`
`.env.`
`.env.dev`
`.env.local`

**.env file:**

```
# Exported firebase functions:config:export command on 24/02/2022`
MAILJET_KEY="XXXX"
MAILJET_SECRET="XXXX"
STRAVA_SECRET="XXXX"
STRAVA_ID="XXXX"
```

2 - I updated the source code to manage `process.env.MY_VARIABLE`

```
const mailjet = require('node-mailjet').connect(process.env.MAILJET_KEY, process.env.MAILJET_SECRET);
```

3 - I ran `npm run serve` or deploy the function but `process.env.MY_VARIABLE` return undefined

```
Error: Mailjet API_KEY is required
```

**Do i run a something special to migrate from functions.config to process.env ??? **

*Note: I've recently managed `process.env` iin a new project and it's works fine !*

Thx

Comment: If you're running the functions locally, the documentation states that you need to have a .runtimeconfig.json in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_functions_configuration_optional)

Answer (score 4):

My issue after the migration was that the `process.env` was not ready on initial emulators startup.
Ref: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4239#issuecomment-1063763689

`functions/index.js:`

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as callable from "./callables";

// Not possible
export const someFunction = someFunctionInit(process.env.APP_ENV);
```

So I needed to move the process.env usage within the function itself,

Comment: I've noticed the same, and my env variables weren't migrated from a config file.
In my case, I'm trying to call admin.initializeApp and pass it the name of a file that contains a config JSON object for the credential value.
Still not sure what I'll do yet, since I want this to depend on environment..

Comment: Thank you Hugo, that was exactly my issue.